# How to change php variable value using wp setting api

Tags: plugins, settings-api

How can I change var $failed_login_limit = "2";    var $lockout_duration   = "10";  value by using wp setting api?

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Jeba_Limit_Login_Attempts' ) ) {
    class Jeba_Limit_Login_Attempts {

        var $failed_login_limit = "2";                    //Number of authentification accepted
        var $lockout_duration   = "10";                 //Stop authentification process for 30 minutes: 60*30 = 1800
        var $transient_name     = 'attempted_login';    //Transient used

        public function __construct() {
            add_filter( 'authenticate', array( $this, 'check_attempted_login' ), 30, 3 );
            add_action( 'wp_login_failed', array( $this, 'login_failed' ), 10, 1 );
        }

        /**
         * Lock login attempts of failed login limit is reached
         */
        public function check_attempted_login( $user, $username, $password ) {
            if ( get_transient( $this->transient_name ) ) {
                $datas = get_transient( $this->transient_name );

                if ( $datas['tried'] >= $this->failed_login_limit ) {
                    $until = get_option( '_transient_timeout_' . $this->transient_name );
                    $time = $this->when( $until );

                    //Display error message to the user when limit is reached 
                    return new WP_Error( 'too_many_tried', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You have reached authentification limit, you will be able to try again in %1$s.' ) , $time ) );
                }
            }

            return $user;
        }


        /**
         * Add transient
         */
        public function login_failed( $username ) {
            if ( get_transient( $this->transient_name ) ) {
                $datas = get_transient( $this->transient_name );
                $datas['tried']++;

                if ( $datas['tried'] <= $this->failed_login_limit )
                    set_transient( $this->transient_name, $datas , $this->lockout_duration );
            } else {
                $datas = array(
                    'tried'     => 1
                );
                set_transient( $this->transient_name, $datas , $this->lockout_duration );
            }
        }


        /**
         * Return difference between 2 given dates
         * @param  int      $time   Date as Unix timestamp
         * @return string           Return string
         */
        private function when( $time ) {
            if ( ! $time )
                return;

            $right_now = time();

            $diff = abs( $right_now - $time );

            $second = 1;
            $minute = $second * 60;
            $hour = $minute * 60;
            $day = $hour * 24;

            if ( $diff < $minute )
                return floor( $diff / $second ) . ' secondes';

            if ( $diff < $minute * 2 )
                return "about 1 minute ago";

            if ( $diff < $hour )
                return floor( $diff / $minute ) . ' minutes';

            if ( $diff < $hour * 2 )
                return 'about 1 hour';

            return floor( $diff / $hour ) . ' hours';
        }
    }
}

//Enable it:
new Jeba_Limit_Login_Attempts();
```

Check my full code

function jeba_wp_latest_jquery_d() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('init', 'jeba_wp_latest_jquery_d');

if ( ! class_exists( 'Jeba_Limit_Login_Attempts' ) ) {
    class Jeba_Limit_Login_Attempts {

```
    var $failed_login_limit = "2";                    //Number of authentification accepted
    var $lockout_duration   = "10";                 //Stop authentification process for 30 minutes: 60*30 = 1800
    var $transient_name     = 'attempted_login';    //Transient used

    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'authenticate', array( $this, 'check_attempted_login' ), 30, 3 );
        add_action( 'wp_login_failed', array( $this, 'login_failed' ), 10, 1 );
    }

    public function check_attempted_login( $user, $username, $password ) {
        if ( get_transient( $this->transient_name ) ) {
            $datas = get_transient( $this->transient_name );

            if ( $datas['tried'] >= $this->failed_login_limit ) {
                $until = get_option( '_transient_timeout_' . $this->transient_name );
                $time = $this->when( $until );

                return new WP_Error( 'too_many_tried', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You have reached authentification limit, you will be able to try again in %1$s.' ) , $time ) );
            }
        }

        return $user;
    }


    public function login_failed( $username ) {
        if ( get_transient( $this->transient_name ) ) {
            $datas = get_transient( $this->transient_name );
            $datas['tried']++;

            if ( $datas['tried'] <= $this->failed_login_limit )
                set_transient( $this->transient_name, $datas , $this->lockout_duration );
        } else {
            $datas = array(
                'tried'     => 1
            );
            set_transient( $this->transient_name, $datas , $this->lockout_duration );
        }
    }


    private function when( $time ) {
        if ( ! $time )
            return;

        $right_now = time();

        $diff = abs( $right_now - $time );

        $second = 1;
        $minute = $second * 60;
        $hour = $minute * 60;
        $day = $hour * 24;

        if ( $diff < $minute )
            return floor( $diff / $second ) . ' secondes';

        if ( $diff < $minute * 2 )
            return "about 1 minute ago";

        if ( $diff < $hour )
            return floor( $diff / $minute ) . ' minutes';

        if ( $diff < $hour * 2 )
            return 'about 1 hour';

        return floor( $diff / $hour ) . ' hours';
    }
}
```

}

new Jeba_Limit_Login_Attempts();

function jeba_options_page(){

```
 add_options_page( 'jeba_manu_title', 'jeba menu', 'manage_options', 'jeba-option-page', 'jebal_options_page_function', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ),8 );
```

}
add_action('admin_menu','jeba_options_page');

function jeba_register_settings() {
    register_setting( 'bappiscroll_up_p_options', 'jeba_demo_options_default', 'jeba_validate_options' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'jeba_register_settings' );

$jeba_demo_options_default = array(
    'jeba_use_demo' => 5,
    'jeba_use_demo_two' => 1800,
);

```
if ( is_admin() ) :
```

function jebal_options_page_function(){?>

### scroll up setting

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">
```

```
<table class="form-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><label for="jeba_use_demo">scroll Distance</label></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="" value="<?php echo stripslashes($settings['jeba_use_demo']); ?>" id="jeba_use_demo" name="jeba_demo_options_default[jeba_use_demo]"/><p class="description">Distance from top/bottom before showing element (px)<br/>Best position is 200px to 300px</p>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><label for="jeba_use_demo_two">scroll Speed</label></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="" value="<?php echo stripslashes($settings['jeba_use_demo_two']); ?>" id="jeba_use_demo_two" name="jeba_demo_options_default[jeba_use_demo_two]"/><p class="description">You can add your scroll Speed<br/>Speed back to top (ms) like auto,200,300,400</p>
                </td>
        </tr>

</tbody>
```

```
<?php 
 }
```

// 7. Add validate options. 
function jeba_validate_options( $input ) {
    global $jeba_demo_options_default,$jeba_control_radio_mode;

```
$settings = get_option( 'jeba_demo_options_default', $jeba_demo_options_default );




$prev=$settings['layout_only'];
if(!array_key_exists($input['layout_only'],$jeba_control_radio_mode))
$input['layout_only']=$prev;
```

return $input;
}

```
endif;  //3. EndIf is_admin()
```

function jeba_use_activator(){
global $jeba_demo_options_default;

$bappiscroll_up_settings=get_option('jeba_demo_options_default','$jeba_demo_options_default');

```
    $failed_login_limit = $bappiscroll_up_settings['jeba_use_demo'];;                    //Number of authentification accepted
   $lockout_duration   = $bappiscroll_up_settings['jeba_use_demo_two'];;                 //Stop authentification process for 30 minutes: 60*30 = 1800
```

}

add_action('wp_head','jeba_use_activator');

Comment: Do you mean saving it using the Settings API? As a WordPress option?

Comment: Yes, I want to change var $failed_login_limit = "2"; var $lockout_duration = "10"; here value 2 and 10 change by using wp setting api

Answer (score 1):

Save them using `update_option('failed_login_limit', 2);` then call them by using var `$failed_login_limit = get_option('failed_login_limit');`.

Use the same syntax for the other variables, as well.

Comment: Try like this  $failed_login_limit = $settings['jeba_use_demo'];; but not working?

Comment: Of course not. Did you register a settings group? Try reading the WordPress Codex for more details.

Comment: Please check once my full function